# JdbcTemplate select данных частями

Tags: java, select, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Нет возможности выполнить весь select запрос к БД разу т.к. таблица очень большая и это приводит к outOfMemoty.

есть ли решение например в цикле или как то еще вытаскивать данные скажем по 1000 строк за один select?

Comment: Например, https://easycodeforall.com/implement-pagination.html
А что мешает использовать Repository и Pageable?